# LocalStorage not working after storing token

Tags: reactjs, jwt, local-storage

I am storing JWT token in LocalStorage after Login success is dispatched and routing to next component. But the next component API call is not able to take LocalStored token.

If i refresh the page and click again, it is accepting the token. Dont know the issue.

This is Axios Instance and Login Dispatch respectively

```
const instance = axios.create({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('accessToken'),
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    validateStatus: (status) => status === 200
});
```

```
export function checkLogin(data, history) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return dispatch(makeAPIRequest(loginAPI, data)).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.success == 1) {
                localStorage.removeItem('accessToken')
                localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.data.token)
                dispatch({ type: STORE_SESSION_TOKEN, authenticated: response.data.data.auth, token: response.data.data.token,userDetails: response.data.data.user });
                history.push('/dashboard')
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Expecting to take token from Localstorage from very next call from Dashboard. But that doesn't happen. says no token and redirects to Login

Comment: When are you calling... axios.create ?? As you see checkLogin is async so, maybe you are calling before you get the token

Comment: Yes. I m calling in axios.create. I am storing token once i got from Check login and routing to dashboard where i call Dashboard API and here i gets error saying token doesn't exist

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to read the token before you put it in the storage.

Answer (score 1):

Your instance is created and therefore set BEFORE you got the token. You can do as others suggested, but I prefer the built-in solution that Axios offers for cases like this and a good pattern to get under your belt - INTERCEPTORS.

A quick demo is you create your instance without the token:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  },
});
```

And then use interceptor to augment the data when the need arises to make Axios request to **ensure you have the latest available info** when making an API call:

```
AxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  // Do things immediately before request is sent
  let token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
  config.headers["x-access-token"] = accessToken;
  return config;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you create the axios instance, the token is not available in localStorage.

You should try the default headers of axios:

```
export const AUTHORIZATION = 'authorization'

export const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:3000/api`
})

export const authorize = (token) => {
  if (token) {
    API.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    localStorage.setItem(AUTHORIZATION, token)
  }
}

export const unauthorize = () => {
  delete API.defaults.headers.Authorization
  localStorage.removeItem(AUTHORIZATION)
}

authorize(localStorage.getItem(AUTHORIZATION))
```

When you receive the token from the API in your actions, you have to save it to localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your header dynamically, because the token is not there while creating the instance and it might change later:

```
const JSON_HEADERS = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
};

const getTokenFromStorage = () => localStorage.getItem('token');

const getHeaders = () => getTokenFromStorage().then((token) => {
  if (!token) {
    return JSON_HEADERS;
  }
  return {
    ... JSON_HEADERS,
    'x-access-token': token
  };
});

export const makeAPIRequest = ({ method, url, data }) => {
return axios({
      method,
      url,
      data,
      headers: getHeaders()
    });
}
```