# Token in LocalStorage is there but not being put inside my Axios Instance

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

One of my components is not loading because the token in Local Storage is not being sent in my Axios request.

Here is the flow. I have a `Login` component that sets the token in Local Storage once the user has been Authenticated. Here is that function:

```
   AuthService.authenticateEmployee(employee).then((r) => {
      if (r != null && r.data.jwt != null) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", r.data.jwt);
        console.log(r.data.jwt);
        console.log("nav to tickets now");
        this.props.history.push("/tickets");
      }
    });
  };
```

It then takes you to `/tickets` which is where my problem lies. The `TicketsComponent` tries to
validate the token. If its invalid then it should redirect the user back to the login page.

```
   AuthService.validateToken()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("step 1");
        if (res == undefined || res == null || !token) {
          this.props.history.push("/login");
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("step 2");

        TicketService.getTickets().then((res) => {
          if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({ tickets: res.data });
          }
        });
      });
```

Here is `validateToken()`:

```
  validateToken() {
    console.log(" about to try validating");
    return AxiosInstance.get("authenticate")
      .then("did it")
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

And finally, this is where I have pinpointed the problem to:

```
const AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${getTokenFromLocalStorage()}` },
});

function getTokenFromLocalStorage() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  console.log("the token from local storage is -> " + token);
  if (token === null) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return token;
}

export default AxiosInstance;
```

If I hardcode the value of the Authorization header to have the same token that is in LocalStorage, then it works. But not when I try to use the `getTokenFromLocalStorage` function. The function does not even seem to get called. The `console.log()` is not being printed at all. What is going on? How can I embed my token into this request correctly?

EDIT: I double checked my LocalStorage in developer tools. It was empty before clicking the login button. When I click login, then the token gets populated as it should as seen here:
[localStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHwFD.png)
However, it still failed to log me in.
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdG0E.png)

***IMPORTANT:*** So it seems like my `getTokenFromLocalStorage` only gets called when the Axios Instance is created and not each time it’s used. How can I fix this so that the function gets called every time I use the AxiosInstance?

**UPDATE**: I found out that the token is definitely not being retrieved from `getTokenFromLocalStorage` since this is the header being sent in the request:
[Request Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYBju.png)

However, I can call `localStorage.getItem("token")` from inside the `TicketsComponent` AFTER clicking login and AFTER setting the token in the header and it displays the correct token. And I posted an image showing that the token is being set in LocalStorage after clicking login so what's going on?

UPDATE #2: I found this StackOverflow answer but it is of no use for me. Anyone have any ideas? [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630802/localstorage-not-working-after-storing-token)

Comment: I have a feeling that `getTokenFromLocalStorage` is only being called once when your `AxiosInstance` is created onLoad. If I'm right, you'd be checking local storage->getting and empty value->passing something like 'Bearer undefined' in your header with each request. Have you checked local storage in your developer tools to verify the token is being saved? Have you checked the network tab to see if your token validation request is being sent and what headers are included with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. The solution was to use interceptors, a part of Axios Instances. Using interceptors allows you to dynamically set the header for each request since it can change at any time.

```
const AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
});

AxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  // Do something before request is sent
  let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
  return config;
});

export default AxiosInstance;
```

And then it worked.

Comment: I came to write this. Yes this is the accepted solution.